# Compare two attribute columns and only keep the first instance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have a point shapefile that I ran the ArcGIS geoprocessing tool *Near* on resulting in a table of which points are near one another. The two columns that I am interested in are **pointid** and **NEAR_FID**. I want to compare these two columns and keep only the records where the **pointid** is noted first. For example:

given the following table

```
pointid NEAR_ID
1       2
2       1
```

I would only expect the feature corresponding to **pointid** 1 to be returned. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean where `pointid` has the lesser of the two values?

Comment: @Aaron oh gosh. I've been at this for too long today. You're right. Please place that down as an answer so I can give you karma or whatever it's called on here...

Comment: I think it is about finding twins http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202766/removing-duplicate-pairs-in-near-table/202934#202934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [Select (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000) with the following SQL query `" pointid  < NEAR_ID "`.

```
import arcpy

in_shp = r'C:\path\to\inshp.shp'
out_shp = r'C:\path\to\outshp.shp'

arcpy.Select_analysis(in_shp, out_shp, where_clause = " pointid  < NEAR_ID ")
```

Alternatively, if you need to run a selection on a feature layer for further analysis (i.e. without creating an output featureclass) use [Select Layer By Attribute (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000). For example:

```
import arcpy

in_shp = r'C:\path\to\inshp.shp'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_shp, "shp_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("shp_lyr", "ADD_TO_SELECTION", where_clause = " pointid  < NEAR_ID ")

# Run some analysis...
```

Comment: I believe there is a flaw in this approach that could have a drastic impact on the results. The Near tool is giving the closest point for each point in the dataset. In *some* cases, these happen to result in pairs - but they won't always do so and @jwx should be aware of this and how Near is working. Add PointID 7 Near_FID 2 to the list. It will fail this selection criteria and be eliminated, even if there are no closer points to 7. Unless 7 is closest to another, all record of it will be lost. And if it did stay that record would falsely indicate 7's closest match. See Felix's comment.